# Why does my form not appear when connecting to a socket in the Load event?

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets

The form from this code does not appear. How can I get it to show? Through the console, everything works.

```
 void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String host = Dns.GetHostName();//name kompa
            //ip pc
            IPAddress ip = Dns.GetHostByName(host).AddressList[0];
            const int port = 2222;
            label1.Text = host;
            label2.Text = "Сервер запущен на " + ip.ToString() + ":" + port.ToString();
            server.serversocket = new Socket(ip.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            server.serversocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(ip, port));
            server.serversocket.Listen(100);

            //ошибочка в цикле
            while (server.work)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("dsff");
                Socket handle = server.serversocket.Accept();
                richTextBox1.AppendText("новое подключение" + handle.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
                new user(handle);


            }
```

Comment: Hanging-up the UI thread with a while() loop is one of the most basic GUI programming mistakes.  Use a worker thread.

Comment: and also, looping/long running work in the OnLoad is not recommended, the form is still not displayed at that stage. OnShown is better than. But please follow @HansPassant advice.

Answer (score 1):

As Hans Passant said, you are blocking the GUI thread with a while loop. That will just not do. Events must return asap and can never run indefinitely. And this Form_Load can not return until the server **stops** working.

It is very common mistake and basically the reason we all went crazy for multitasking and multithreading this century. You can't even do a word processor without it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You are blocking the ui thread. Using a separate [thread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx) for the synchronous socket server would be a solution. The other option would be to use an asynchronous socket so that the execution of the application is not blocked while it waits for a connection. Based on the socket code [samples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitSocketServer();
    }

    internal void InitSocketServer()
    {
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
        var ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);
        try
        {
            Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
            listener.Listen(100);
            listener.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, listener);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

        string data = null;

        while (true)
        {
            var bytes = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes);
            data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);
            if (data.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1)
            {
                break;
            }
        }


        MessageBox.Show(handler.RemoteEndPoint + " : " + data);

        byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

        handler.Send(msg);
        handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        handler.Close();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Test button click");
    }
}
```